# SQL returns null data

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to remove values ​​that has null result (second row)

[image: I need to remove values ​​that has null result (second row)]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images. (And most of us don't click links.)

Comment: Spend some time and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [mcve], to ask questions easier to answer.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query that you posted uses correlated sub queries to get the results that could easily achieved with a left join. Changing that left join into an inner join will get rid of the nulls as long as you do not have nulls in the name column of the emp table.

```
    select e.empno,e.ename,mngr.name 
    from emp e 
    inner join emp mngr on e.mgr=mngr.empno
```